# Infinity Display: In a two-monitor setup, how can I map the right side of each monitor to the left side of the other monitor and same for up and down?

Tags: windows-10, display, multiple-monitors

This question only applies to multiple-display setups with exactly 2 monitors. I'm running Windows 10.

I know that I can rearrange how the monitors extend with **Start** > **Settings** > **System** > **Display** > **Rearrange your displays**. However, I want the mouse to **Always** move to the other monitor when I put it past the edge on one monitor. I want an **infinity display** where every side of each monitor is mapped to the **opposite** side of the other monitor.

How can I map the right side of each monitor to the left side of the other monitor, vice-versa, and the same for top and bottom and vice-versa?

I created a picture in paint. Essentially, a matrix like this, if big enough, would work: [Infinity Display .jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JE3a.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Multiple Monitors](https://www.actualtools.com/articles/detail.php?ID=1322) program does what you want, although it's not free. It has a free trial to check it out.

I tested it with 2 monitors. Going right from right one does send you to the left one like in PacMan, but going up or down only sends you in the same monitor, not the other one (which would me a bit disorienting in my opinion).